# nodejs, Loopback change model name / table name (with mysql)

Tags: node.js, loopback

use Loopback(nodejs) with mysql.

I want to change the model name/table name. (different name)

I don't want to see table name (in API URL)

```
table name = 'super_member'

model name = 'member'

api url = '/api/member/';
```

what can I do?

Comment: maybe, I resoved this problem. just set 'plural' in model.json......thinks watch this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize models by adding a `mysql` property on the model and/or on the properties :

```
{
  "name": "yourModelName",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "mysql": {
    "schema": "YOUR DATABASE NAME",
    "table": "YOUR MYSQL TABLE NAME"
  },
  "properties": {
    "PropertyOne": {
      "type": "Number"
      "required": true,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "YOUR MYSQL COLUMN NAME",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 10,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      },
      "_selectable": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: Wow, I love it, this solution. Thank you very much. You are good teacher!!

Comment: what about mongodb ?